# ShowcaseView slow down my App thrice

Tags: android, performance, slowdown, showcaseview

I get used to working with a Showcase View in my app (newest v5.0). I'm using **Fragments** in my app. My Android is 4.4.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fairy_mouse3, container, false);
    ...
    sv = new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTarget(new ViewTarget(rootView.findViewById(R.id.keyboard)))
        .build();
    ...
    return rootView;
}
```

My app worked very fast but when I add `ShowcaseView`, my app slow down. When `ShowcaseView` is visible then I have 1 fps and some freezes. It's very strange because after I close `ShowcaseView` my app start working very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not unexpected - there's a lot of drawing that ShowcaseView has to do. I wouldn't recommend using ShowcaseView on screens that are moving or animating.

Comment: Hi, my activity hasn't animation. When I tap simple button i have freeze.